# How to Format Hijri Date

Tags: android, calendar, gregorian-calendar, hijri, time4j

I'm using **time4A** to do transformation from `Islamic Hjiri to Gregorian Date` and vice versa. I'm not able to find a way to format **Hijri Date** to "`yyyy/mmm/dd`" pattern.

Here is the code to convert from **Gregorian to Hijri** :

```
     CalendarVariant variant =
                    PlainDate.of(2016, 02, 12)
                            .transform(HijriCalendar.class, HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA);

System.out.println(variant.toString());
```

I got this `AH-1437-05-03[islamique-umalqura]`

I need some thing like: `1437-05-03`

So, How I can format **Hijri Date** ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer. If you don't get an immediate reply you could also ask the question directly on the issue tracker of Time4J.

**About your question, two points:**

a) Don't use abstract interface types but concrete types. Here, replace `CalendarVariant` by [HijriCalendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HijriCalendar.html), otherwise you will handle a raw type due to unresolved generics.

b) The formatter class `ChronoFormatter` can handle formatting (and parsing as well). You only need to feed it with following informations: pattern string, pattern type, locale and chronology. It is also immutable and can be stored in a static final constant. Example:

```
HijriCalendar hijriDate =
    PlainDate.of(2016, 02, 12).transform(
        HijriCalendar.class,
        HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA
    );
ChronoFormatter<HijriCalendar> hf =
    ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
        "yyyy-MM-dd", // mmm as given by you would be in minutes in CLDR-standard
        PatternType.CLDR,
        Locale.ROOT,
        HijriCalendar.family()
    );
System.out.println(hf.format(hijriDate)); // 1437-05-03
```

The given example just uses the root locale because you only want a numerical representations using standard digits. But of course you can have a formatted representation using other numerical systems if you want (then the locale matters, or you even set an [explicit format attribute](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/NumberSystem.html)).